# Compressing NLog logs sent through UDP

Tags: c#, .net, logging, nlog

Is there any way that i can configure nlog config file to compress and send logs everyday? I mean now it's sending them as simple logs. I'm asking because i know it's possible while using target type = file, but i don't know if that's possible with type = network.

i know it's possible with this (but it's for file target, not for network)

```
archiveFileName="W:\LOGS\Archived\log.{#}.zip"
archiveEvery="Hour"
archiveNumbering="DateAndSequence"
archiveDateFormat="yyyyMMddHH"
maxArchiveFiles="72"
```

My config:

```
<targets async="true">
      <target xsi:type="Network" name="GelfUdp" address="udp://00000000" layout="${gelf:facility=WebApi:IncludeAllProperties=true:IncludeMdlc=true:IncludeGdc=true}">
      </target>
    <target name="LOCALUDP" xsi:type="Network" address="udp://00000000" newLine="false" maxMessageSize="65000" encoding="utf-8" layout="${log4jxmlevent}" />
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="GelfUdp" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="LOCALUDP" />
  </rules>
```

I want my nlog to send compressed logs everyday.

Comment: The [NLog NetworkTarget](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Network-target) will send LogEvents to the network-address, and the remote host will then receive and process the LogEvents. If the remote-host writes to a file, then it must handle file-compression in whatever way it likes. Notice the [NLog NetworkTarget](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Network-target) can send LogEvent compressed with GZip if the remote-host can handle it.